# Externalizing figures in consistent size

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-external

I'm using pgfplots to plot figures, then I'm using the externalize library to output standalone pdfs, which I include in another document. The problem is that the outputted standalone figures have different widths and when including them all with the same width, the font sizes will differ. Is there a way to get the font sizes to be same for all the figures when doing the workflow as I described.

The MWE, which has two pgfplots figures, both have the same width specified in the tikzpicture, one has bigger ytick labels, everything else is the same. The produced standalone figures have different widths. And when I include them in another document, the fonts will be different.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz_figures/]

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=7.5cm,
        xmin = 0, xmax = 5,
        ymin = 0, ymax = 5,
        xlabel={x},
        ylabel={y}
        ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=7.5cm,
        xmin = 0, xmax = 5,
        ymin = 0, ymax = 5,
        ytick = {0.1},
        xlabel={x},
        ylabel={y}
        ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `ytick` at 0.1 in the second plot hence the `ylabel` moves to the right considering that extra space. You can make the position of the `ylabel` to be fixed by

```
ylabel style={at={(rel axis cs:-0.1,0.5)}}
```

You will find various `cs` (like `ticklabel cs`) systems for this in the manual (besides `rel axis cs`, that I have used)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz_figures/]

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=7.5cm,
        xmin = 0, xmax = 5,
        ymin = 0, ymax = 5,
        xlabel={x},
        ylabel={y},
        ylabel style={at={(rel axis cs:-0.1,0.5)}}
        ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=7.5cm,
        xmin = 0, xmax = 5,
        ymin = 0, ymax = 5,
        ytick = {0.1},
        xlabel={x},
        ylabel={y},
        ylabel style={at={(rel axis cs:-0.1,0.5)}}
        ]
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]